# The meaning of "the lanes"

Tags: meaning

I saw a sentence when I read my textbook.
It says

> The Lanes go to church every Sunday morning to listen to the minister preach the Bible.

But,all I know about "lane" is something like a narrow road or other routines.
Can you tell me what the meaning of " The Lanes" is in this sentence?
Thanks.

Comment: Mr. and Mrs Lane and maybe their kids

Comment: Lane is also a family name ( last name/surname). It means the Lane family goes to church... It could be Mr. and Mrs Lane only, or if they have children including them too or even any other relatives they have that choose to go to church with them.

Comment: Ah… now, I get it. Thanks for your help.":)

Comment: It doesn't need to be a "Mr. and Mrs." It could be two sisters or two cousins. Or, really, *any* group of people with the last name *Lane*.

Comment: For future questions about basic English, you might find that our sibling site [ell.se] provides better support.

Answer (score 7):

It is a surname. It is capitalized because it is a proper noun, that distinguishes it from 'lane' as in 'road lane'.